# Syntax error when using sequelize postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
sequelize: 1.7.0
pg: 2.11.1
posgreSql: 9.3 (pg server on my pc)
```

I have app that is using following config:

```
db: 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/dbname'
```

And it works with `sequelize` and `mysql` dialect.
When I change it to:

```
db: 'postgres://user:pass@localhost/dbname'
```

and dialect to `postgres` and try to `sequelize.sync()` I get following error:

```
{
   "message":"syntax error at or near \"(\"",
   "name":"error",
   "stack":"error: syntax error at or near \"(\"\n    at Connection.parseE (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:561:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:390:17)\n    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:92:20)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)\n    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)\n    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)\n---------------------------------------------\n    at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.failure.CustomEventEmitter.fail.CustomEventEmitter.error (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:93:10)\n    at exec (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:92:14)\n    at onError (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:72:11)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)\n    at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.emit (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:61:33)\n    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:131:17)\n---------------------------------------------\n    at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.failure.CustomEventEmitter.fail.CustomEventEmitter.error (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:93:10)\n    at exec (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:92:14)\n    at onError (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/query-chainer.js:72:11)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)\n    at module.exports.CustomEventEmitter.emit (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:61:33)\n    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/me/Desktop/node/myapp/node_modules/sequelize/lib/emitters/custom-event-emitter.js:131:17)",
   "code":"42601"
},
"msg":"uncaughtException",
"time":"2014-03-31T14:17:29.496Z",
"v":0
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Before I created `dbname` database in pg there was error `missing database` so I guess sequelize is connected to pg but it generates some syntax errors in pgsql code??

---

the problem was that in model schema I had Sequelize.INTEGER(11) - and postgres does not allow to pass 11 as a size of INTEGER - this will be solved in 2.x.x version of Sequelize (You can find issue corresponding to this problem on sequelize github repo).

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize and postgres work well for me. Did you set dialect, protocol, port correctly in config.js like this

```
{
  "development":{
    "username":"name",
    "password":"pass",
    "database":"db",
    "dialect":"postgres",
    "protocol":"postgres",
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "port":"5432"
  },
...
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write that this is solved - the problem was that in model schema I had `Sequelize.INTEGER(11)` - and postgres does not allow to pass `11` as a size of INTEGER - this will be solved in `2.x.x` version of Sequelize (You can find issue corresponding to this problem on sequelize github repo).